# How to access a function in interactive namespace in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In a ipython script notebook I want to have something like:

```
from mod import run

def initialize():
    print("In!")

run()
```

The script makes the assumption the user needs to define a function initialize, and the run() should test if it is defined and invoke it.

How should I define run() to get a reference to a "initialized" function defined in the interactive namespace ?

Comment: Why not make the function an explicit parameter of `run`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe excellent idea -- else you need to use `sys._getframe` to identify the caller's frame, and that's specifically warned against in the docs!

Comment: You could make run a method of a class which defines `initialize` but raises an exception if it is not over-written.

Comment: The interactive namespace is `__main__`, so you could do `import __main__` in `mod`.  However, I agree it's better to pass the function explicitly.

Comment: @BrenBarn : you are right, `__main__` works. I have tested it before as I would have expected it too, but must have misspelled it and thought it wasn't working. Thanks.

Comment: understand that it doesn't look good programming style, but this is to use interactively in ipython to perform agent simulation with convention initialize,step,shutdown functions. I want to avoid to have the user write run(initialize,step,shutdown) every time. In fact the whole framework uses proper class hierarchies, etc, but I made a small "shell" around it to be used interactively without classes.

Comment: In the long run there are usually better ways to do something then funky introspection in module name spaces, that's what classes are for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach -

Inside the module:

```
class MyHandler(object):  
    def __init__(self, *args): 
      """ Init stuff """
    def run(self, *args): 
        self.initializer(*args)
        """do running stuff"""
        pass
    def initializer(self): 
      raise Exception("Initializer must be defined") 
    def shutdown(self): 
        """default cleanup stuff"""
        pass
```

Then the Ipython workflow could be something like:

```
from mod import MyHandler
new_handler = MyHandler() 
def add_method(obj, meth): 
    obj.__dict__[meth.__name__] = meth.__get__(obj, obj.__class__)
def intializer(self): 
    print("In!") 
add_method(new_handler, initializer) 
new_handler.run()
```